# How to distribute content to columns with border between them? (wordpress)

Tags: html, css, border, multiple-columns

I am making an event list for music band site based on wordpress.

List has two columns layout and i need to distribute each event so that first goes into left column, second goes right, third goes left and so on.

Would be pretty easy task, but i have to make a **border between columns**!

I made a distribution by making each `.event` block `float:left; width:45%;` but these are not actually columns and i cannot add a border.

I tried also css3 multicolumn layout but it didn't work for me.

here is my code http://jsfiddle.net/jxe8bgyv/1/

Comment: What do you mean you can't add a border? I can actually add one.

Comment: i mean border between columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
.event:nth-child(even) {
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! I changed it to :nth-child(odd) and border-right, but it doesn't do a border for the first element http://jsfiddle.net/jxe8bgyv/4/

Comment: Could you provide some image where I could see what the code has to do?

Comment: It's responsive, but couldn't be done without wrapping `li` contents with `div`:  
http://jsfiddle.net/jxe8bgyv/5/

Answer (score 0):

```
.event:nth-child(odd){
    border-right: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! But somehow it doesn't draw it for the first element